# Set Desired Capacity error during the bootstrap of the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, coreos, coreos-ignition

I've created an ASG with a min size and desired capacity set to `1`. The EC2 instance is bind to an Application Load Balancer. I use ignition to define the user data of the Launch Configuration. I run defined in Ignition a script which execute these two commands:

```
    # Set the ASG Desired Capacity - get CoreOS metadata
    ASG_NAME=$(/usr/bin/docker run --rm --net=host \
        "$AWSCLI_IMAGE" aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances \
        --region="$COREOS_EC2_REGION" --instance-ids="$COREOS_EC2_INSTANCE_ID" \
        --query 'AutoScalingInstances[].AutoScalingGroupName' --output text)

    echo "Check desired capacity of Auto Scaling group..."
    # shellcheck disable=SC2154,SC2086
    /usr/bin/docker run --rm --net=host \
        $AWSCLI_IMAGE aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity \
        --region="$COREOS_EC2_REGION" --auto-scaling-group-name "$ASG_NAME" \
        --desired-capacity 3 \
        --honor-cooldown
```

The problem is that I get as error `ScalingActivityInProgress` so I can't change the desired capacity.

First I'd like to understand the root cause. Is it maybe because the ALB is not healthy when I run the above commands?

Answer (score 0):

Solved removing `honor-cooldown` param from the request